# Dealing with non-nullable warning in constructor chain

Tags: c#

How to deal with the "Non-nullable property 'S2' must contain a non-null value"-warning for the private constructor in the following example:

```
 #nullable enable
 class X {...}
 class Y {...}
 class Z {...}     
 class C {
   public string S1 { get; }
   public string S2 { get; }
   private C(Z z) => S1 = GenerateS1FromZ(z);
   public C(Z z, X x) : this(z) => S2 = GenerateS2FromX(x);
   public C(Z z, Y y) : this(z) => S2 = GenerateS2FromY(y);

   private static string GenerateS1FromZ(Z z) { ... }
   private static string GenerateS2FromX(X x) { ... }
   private static string GenerateS2FromY(Y y) { ... }
 }
```

`S1` must be initialized in a constructor, since it has no setter. `S2` can be initialized in two ways, so there are two public constructors.

Assume that `S1` and `S2` are just placeholders for a few more properties. Therefore, it is not practical to pass the value for `S2` to the private constructor as parameter or to initialize `S1` in both public constructors.

Under this assumption the code above is ok I think, but the non-nullable-warning does not work as I wish. One could add `S2=null!;` in the private constructor to avoid the warning, but that seems to be a hack.

Comment: The language rules don't prevent that private constructor from being used from elsewhere within the same class and it doesn't attempt to prove that such usage doesn't occur. *If* `new C(new Z());` occurred somewhere else in the class, `S2` would indeed be unintialized.

Comment: You could always use `#pragma warning disable CS8618` and `#pragma warning restore CS8618` around the private constructor to suppress the warning, along with a comment as to why it's ok to suppress it.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Using the pragma has a similar effect as ```S2=null!;``` which I think is more a workaround than a solution.

Comment: The pragma avoids a redundant assignment, however.

Comment: `this(s1)` should be `this(z)` in the code. And the _S1 and S2 are just placeholders for a few more properties_  sounds like they could/should be refactored out to *separate* classes/structs. Then at least your assignments in `C`'s constructor will reduce and you implement the assignments only once for each set of props.

Comment: If you're calling the private ctor via `this` only, why not make it a method and use [`MemberNotNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute

Comment: @Youssef13 If S1 is initialized outside a constructor, it needs a (at least private) setter. But I want to ensure that S1 cannot be modified later on.

Comment: @GWimpassinger The refactoring idea is the best approach so far. If you formulate this as an answer, I will make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to your requirement

> Assume that S1 and S2 are just placeholders for a few more properties. Therefore, it is not practical to pass the value for S2 to the private constructor as parameter or to initialize S1 in both public constructors.

This is a good hint to do some refactoring and extract those properties to separate classes or structs. If you do so, you can then pass the values to your private constructor of `C` and remove the non-nullable warning.

Here is a simple example for completeness

```
class S1
{
    public string S1Prop { get; }

    public S1(Z z) => S1Prop = GenerateFrom(z);
    private static string GenerateFrom(Z z) { /* ... */ return "From z"; }
}

class S2
{
    public string S2Prop { get; }

    public S2(X x) => S2Prop = GenerateFrom(x);
    public S2(Y y) => S2Prop = GenerateFrom(y);
    private static string GenerateFrom(X x) { /* ... */ return "From x"; }
    private static string GenerateFrom(Y y) { /* ... */ return "From y"; }
}

class C
{
    public S1 S1 { get; }
    public S2 S2 { get; }

    private C(S1 s1, S2 s2) { S1 = s1; S2 = s2; }

    public C(Z z, X x) : this(new S1(z), new S2(x)) { }
    public C(Z z, Y y) : this(new S1(z), new S2(y)) { }
}
```

Depending on your requirements you may also remove the dependency on the classes
`X`, `Y` and `Z` by making the private constructor public and remove the other
two.

```
class C2 // No dependency to X, Y, Z
{
    public S1 S1 { get; }
    public S2 S2 { get; }

    public C2(S1 s1, S2 s2) { S1 = s1; S2 = s2; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although assigning `S2` to `null!` may stop compiler from complaining, it makes code more fragile to further modification because someone else might add new constructor without initializing `S2`.

In my opinion best solution is to create constructor that will assign `S2` and call it everywhere.

```cs
#nullable enable
    class X { }
    class Y { }
    class Z { }
    class C
    {
        public string S1 { get; }
        public string S2 { get; }
        private C(Z z, string s2)
        {
            S1 = GenerateS1FromZ(z);
            S2 = s2; // assign here
        }

        public C(Z z, X x) : this(z, GenerateS2FromX(x)) { } // remove assignment here
        public C(Z z, Y y) : this(z, GenerateS2FromY(y)) { }

        private static string GenerateS1FromZ(Z z) => "";
        private static string GenerateS2FromX(X x) => "";
        private static string GenerateS2FromY(Y y) => "";
    }
```

Comment: The OP appeared to already rule this out - "it is not practical to pass the value for S2 to the private constructor as parameter"